# chrome headless mode with dom distiller

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

For one my projects, we need to extract the distilled content of a crawled webpage. We want to be able to this as an internal service on the server side without the browser. I have been working on using the headless mode of chromium with the distill functionality to be able to do this. Has anyone tried doing this in this forum? Even if you have not done, could someone share some insights on how to potentially do this ?

Thanks,
Praveen.